Bibtex Latex-Workshop Missing endcsname inserted
I am pretty new to latex working in linux with textlive and vscode with the extension Latex-Workshop, it cost me a bit of time making it work together but at the end it is working fine except i keep getting the error in the title "Missing endcsname inserted" on one particular entry in my bibfile:
@article{llavearticulo,
  author  = {Arthur B Cummings and David Eftekhary and Frank G House},
  title   = {The accurate determination of college students
             coefficients of friction},
  journal = {Journal of Sketchy Physics},
  volume  = {13},
  year    = {2003},
  number  = {2},
  pages   = {46--129}
}

It is just a dummy article from a latex course.
MWE:
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage[a4paper, margin=2.54cm, head=1.27cm, foot=1.27cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[spanish]{cleveref}
\usepackage{url}

\graphicspath{{./images}}

\newcommand{\mychapter}[2]{
    %\setcounter{chapter}{#1}
    %\setcounter{section}{0}
    \chapter*{#1 #2}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1 #2}
    \refstepcounter{chapter}
}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{
    \fancyhf{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}
\pagestyle{plain}

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Índice general}
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{Índice de cuadros}
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{Índice de figuras}

\title{My title}
\author{My myself}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

Otras formas de citas
\begin{itemize}
    \item \cite[p.12]{llavearticulo}
    \item \cite[e.g.][p.12]{llavearticulo}
    \item \cite[e.g.][]{llavearticulo}
    \item \cite[][]{llavearticulo}
    \item \citep{llavearticulo}
    \item \cite*{llavearticulo}
    \item \citep*{llavearticulo}
\end{itemize}


\newpage
\bibliography{sources}
\bibliographystyle{chicago}

\end{document}

Checking the generated files the main.bbl file has the error in the line before the end:
\begin{thebibliography}{}

\bibitem[\protect\citeauthoryear{Cummings, Eftekhary, and House}{Cummings et~al.}{2003}]{llavearticulo}
Cummings, A.~B., D.~Eftekhary, and F.~G. House (2003).
\newblock The accurate determination of college students coefficients of friction.
\newblock {\em Journal of Sketchy Physics\/}~{\em 13\/}(2), 46--129.

\end{thebibliography}

Already looked for previous questions but the only ones remotely similar where ones that used keys with strange characters in the bib file or using underscore in some field.

As an opening aside: in the future please do a better job trimming your MWE. Most of the packages you've loaded are not used in the document, and if you do some preliminary trimming (by commenting out each package one by one and seeing if it impacts the problem), you may have come to the conclusion that the following is a much more minimal example
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{natbib}



\title{My title}
\author{My myself}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

Otras formas de citas
\begin{itemize}
    \item \cite[p.12]{llavearticulo}
    \item \cite[e.g.][p.12]{llavearticulo}
    \item \cite[e.g.][]{llavearticulo}
    \item \cite[][]{llavearticulo}
    \item \citep{llavearticulo}
    \item \cite*{llavearticulo}
    \item \citep*{llavearticulo}
\end{itemize}


\newpage
\bibliography{sources}
\bibliographystyle{chicago}

\end{document}

and that the culprit is babel with the spanish option.
The problem is that babel-spanish creates several shorthands to enable quick typing of accented characters using the standard ASCII character set. Among this is the ability to type ~n and have it compiled to be ñ. Unfortunately, outside of the Spanish babel, the ~ character also inserts a (particular type of) space, and natbib (especially in the chicago style) uses it to do some of the formatting of the bibliography items.
Two possible solutions

If you don't use the babel shorthands at all (based on the MWE you posted it appears you type the document in Unicode and can type characters like ñ directly), the easiest thing is to turn off short hands completely in babel. You do this by adding appropriate options to \uspackage[...]{babel}. Try, for example,
\usepackage[spanish, es-noshorthands, shorthands=off]{babel}


If you do in fact use babel shorthands, you can also turn off the offending shorthand before your bibliography is printed. Try replacing the final few lines of your code with


\newpage
\shorthandoff{~}   % <- turns off the ~ short hand
\bibliography{sources}
\bibliographystyle{chicago}

\end{document}


Thank you for your in depth response, I disabled all shorthands at the beginning and everything is working now. You are right about the bad job i did at trimming the MWE and in the future I will try the approach of commenting packages.
